# trigger Page_Load of a menu control from an iframe of a page

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I have an aspx page, there I have a control that is in charge of the menu of the page. Also I have an iframe where all the pages will be loaded. My main page looks like this:

```
<body class="Main-background">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="SingleColFixter">
        <div id="holder">
            <uc2:ctlMenu ID="ctlMenu1" runat="server" />
            <uc1:Header ID="Header" runat="server" />
            <div id="contentxt">
                <iframe runat="server" id="iframe1" width="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" 
                frameborder="0" src="./frmDashboard.aspx" style="position: relative;" scrolling="no" ></iframe>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <uc1:Footer ID="Footer1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The issue is that I need to call the Page_Load() method of the menu from a control/page of the iframe, this to update the options in the menu.

Basically, I need to refresh the menu with the changes generated from the page inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the menu inside an Ajax update panel together with a hidden button (setting style display:none) and via JavaScript from inside the iframe simulate the click of the button of the parent page.